# how to add an animation image in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a table view. in that I have to add animation image in the cell. I have tried some conditions but still its not working. what a mistake I have done in the below coding.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if([ststus isEqual:@"43"])
{
 NSArray *animationArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"],

                             nil];

   UIImageView *animationView;
    animationView.animationImages=animationArray;
      animationView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 50,36, 36)];
    animationView.animationDuration=90;
    animationView.animationRepeatCount=0;
    [animationView startAnimating];


cell.animation.image= animationView;
} }
```

Last line have a warning:`Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImage *' from 'UIImageView *'`In my table view cell animation image is not appearing.please any one can help me in coding.how can i do this process.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't create a new `ImageView` - there should already be one available on the `UITableViewCell` and you can set its `.animationImages` property directly.

Secondly, you need to assign an image of the same size to the `.image` property too, otherwise the standard `UITableViewCell layoutSubviews()` will leave the labels in their default positions and won't leave space for the animated image.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please change the 'image' property which is of type UIImage * in cell.animation.image to UIImageView * which will remove the above warning of assigning the UIImageView instance to UIImage instance.